# Markers remove when no more value is sent to the specific markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hi everyine please help me, I am trying to do a search filter on my vehicle tracking, the flow is, the servlet queries all data when there is no parameter filter is being sent by ajax. for example, I do have 5 data on query result so there will be 5 markers on the map, the ajax runs every two seconds so when I request a parameter for example only this spesific vehicle would be shown the query result would only be one, supposedly only marker on the screen, but the previous markers are not vanishing and keep up on the screen. how can I reset the markers into 0? can anyone please help me thanks! here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var values = [];
var map;
var markers = [];
function    initMap()
{
            var options = {
                center: {lat: -33.890542, lng: 151.274856},
                zoom: 4
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
            var count = 0; 
            setInterval(function() {
                getGps();
                for(var i = 0; i <= markers.length; i++){
                        markers[i].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(values[count][1],values[count][2]));
                        count++;
                    }
            }, 2000);
} 
function removeMarkers(){
for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
    markers[i].setMap(null);
}
markers=[];
}
function getGps() {
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {    
                if( xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 ) {
                    removeMarkers();
                    var res = xmlhttp.responseText; 
                    console.log(res);
                    var split1 = res.split("|");
                        if(split1[0] != "NOK"){
                            for(var i = 0; i < split1.length; i++){
                                var split2 = split1[i].split(",");
                                String(split2);
                                var holder1 = holder = [split2[0],split2[1],split2[2]];
                                values.push(holder1);;
                                var marker1 = marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, icon: 'images/mapvehicle.png', draggable: true});
                                markers.push(marker1);
                            }
                        }   

                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("POST","GpsPost",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send("txtTerminal="+document.getElementById('txtTerminal').value+"&txtMerchant="+document.getElementById('txtMerchant').value+"&txtAccount="+document.getElementById('txtAccount').value);  
}
```

Comment: 1) The code you posted does **not** (at all) allow to reproduce the issue 2) What have you tried to debug your code? Did you have a look at your javascript console? Any error there? Is it at all calling your function? What happens in there then?

Answer (score -1):

add this function and call it after this line .
     if( xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 ) {

```
function removeMarkers(){
    for(i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers=[]
    values=[]
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing                                 var marker1 = marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, icon: 'images/mapvehicle.png', draggable: true});
 why dont you directly store it in marker1 instead of storing in marker

Comment: my goal here is to remove markers before adding new set of markers depedns on the response on the ajax.

Comment: can you console.log markers length inside remove function

Comment: What about posting code that is valid and correctly formatted?

Comment: yes sir the POST method does it's job and gives the right response. wait up, I'll try it

Comment: console log inside the remove unction shows 0 value for markers, it is working

Comment: after which line you added console.log?

Comment: so that is what you wanted right you didn't wanted any previous markers on map